# <td> tags inside view disappearing when declaration is made on object's associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Been perplexed on this one for a while now. It seems like a simple oversight but I cannot get past it.

**I have a basic table element to list jobs with each row representing an record in the jobs table.**

```
<% if @jobs.any? %>

    <thead>
    <tr>

    <th>Booking ID</th>
    <th>Cleaner</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
```

**When I instantiate the associated model of 'address' assigned to 'addy', the row elements immediately disappear on refresh. Am I missing something here?**

```
    <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
    <% job.address do |addy| %> 

    <tr>

    <td><%= job.id %></td>
    <td><%= job.jrecipient_id %></td>
    <td><%= addy.label %></td>
    <td>No status yet</td>
    <td><%= link_to "Change Appointment", '#' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Cancel Cleaning", job, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %> </td>

    </tr>

    <%#distance_of_time_in_words(job.created_at, Time.now)%>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT: Some more information**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :job
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :address
end
```

Comment: What is the relation between `job` and `address`? Is it a `has_one` or `has_many`?

Comment: has_one updated question with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have '`'undefined method`label' for nil:NilClass'` ' , it means the job you want to display doesn't have an address ( address attribute of Job is Nil). Do you require an address in your validations ?
Otherwise , try to create a job with an address in the console (rails console) and display it after see what you get.

Show us your Job model maybe...

Comment: Ok so when I create a Address record and set it's job_id attribute to that of an existing job, that same job.address still returns nil. I don't have any existing validations yet on either model (Address or Job)

Comment: According to this [link]http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html[link]. you shouldn't have to specify the ID. In the console, try to retrieve a Job in a @job variable (by Job.find() or create a new one), then do address = @job.addresses.create( ---attributes of address, WITHOUT any reference to the job --- ),  then see what it display. See the link, it explains everything, and i think you can solve your problem by looking at the first few pages...

Answer (score 1):

For the case when job has many addresses
    `<% job.address.each do |addy| %>`
or for the case when job has one address
`<% addy = job.address %>`

Comment: Making that change produces a no method error 'undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass' I assure you though that label is an attribute of Address

Comment: May be you need to check if address.present?

Comment: Your answer helped me arrive at my 'aha!' moment. So it turns out there were Address records in the database that weren't associated with any Job records. When it tried to find an associated Address record for the listed job, it was returning nil. I fixed this potential future problem by handling the chance that it could be nil by containing instantiating addy only if job.address is not nil. Thank you!